# Make [phonegap-plugins] a synonym of [cordova-plugins]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Reasons to make [phonegap-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap-plugins) a synonym of [cordova-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova-plugins):

- The [phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap) tab already redirects to [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova) as a synonym.
- The [phonegap-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap-plugins) tag description is a copy of the [cordova-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova-plugins) tag description, basically indicates the Phonegap and Cordova plugins are the same thing:

  > A Cordova (PhoneGap) plugin bridges a bit of functionality between the WebView powering a Cordova application and the native platform the Cordova application is running on.

The request would be for [phonegap-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap-plugins) and [cordova-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova-plugins) tags to be merged into the latter.

Although interestingly, there are 3,984 questions tagged with [phonegap-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap-plugins), while there are only 2,736 questions tagged with [cordova-plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova-plugins). I don't know if/how that would affect this request.