# Time to burninate the [phonegap] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

This is the description of the [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova) tag:

> Apache Cordova (formerly **PhoneGap**) is a framework that

It's clearly stated that Cordova was formerly PhoneGap. But still, I see many people use both of these tags together in their questions.

Here are the burnination criteria as per [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191):

1. **Does it describes the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**
   Answer: Yes because [phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap) has now been changed to [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova). People tag their questions with both these tags. What does this mean then? It is clearly written on the Cordova tag description page.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   Answer: Nope. But still both the tags mean the same and one (most probably [phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap)) must be taken off.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Answer: Yes it adds, but still it is changed to [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova) now!
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   Answer: Of Course, as mentioned on the tag descript, [phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap) is now [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova)

Now, does this tag need to be burninated?

Comment: I too also don't know much about tag burnination and synonymizing. I found that on the tag description page. Also after investigating, I posted this question

Comment: I think it should be four yes-es; the topic is on-topic for the site as far as I can see. Is the name change total, and does Cordova now apply to older editions as well, or would one refer to the pre-name change version as PhoneGap? In any case, four yesses don't make a burninate (even three don't); it's either a synonym in my opinion, or not necessary to act upon at all.

Comment: Related [Make phonegap-plugins a synonym of cordova-plugins](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336016/5211833) and its follow-up [Remove Phonegap as synonym of Cordova tag and make it independent again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337612/5211833)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we should burninate any of these tags as they refer to different technologies that are both on-topic for Stack Overflow:

- [cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cordova): These questions are about the Apache Cordova framework, which was originally named Phonegap, but renamed after Adobe bought it and handed it over to Apache.
- [phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap): These questions refer to what Phonegap is nowadays, which is a framework built on top of Cordova, which provides additional features provided by Adobe.

This has also been mentioned in [Removed Phonegap as synonym of Cordova tag and make it independent again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337612/5211833)

So the tag description is correct (though perhaps it shouldn't be in the excerpt), Cordova was once known as Phonegap, but in its current state, Phonegap is not the same thing as Cordova.

Illustrated:

```
Phonegap ------o---(Additional features by Adobe)--- Phonegap
               └---(Framework renamed)-------------- Cordova
```